# How to use runnable jar in java project by importing it to libs folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I want to use a runnable jar in my java project by including it in my projects libs folder how can i reference it or run it.

so far i am doing this by referencing the jar from my pc but now i want to export my project as jar and wan't to include this runnable jar within my project to let the user use this project as a whole without being any dependency.

Comment: did you try "Package required libraries into generated jar" while exporting runnable jar of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On coding side you can use `ProcessBuilder` to launch any jar located on particular path

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", _JarPath);
//If you need to supply arguments then use
// ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", _JarPath, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: No need to use a ProcessBuilder, it will only complicate things (since 'java' doesn't have to be on the path). You can just call the main method of the class to run. Any needed arguments can be passed to that method.